# Effectively query range of arbitrary data stored in json array

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing, database-design

I am trying to query data stored in an array in a field of type jsonb as follows:

**Data description:**

There is a table named `items` which has 4 columns: `name`, `owner`, `seller`, and `metadata` (`metadata` is the column that I want to query on). The data in `metadata` looks like this:

```
metadata {

  ...
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "rareity"
      "value": "ultra-rare",
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "color"
      "value": "red",
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "attract"
      "value": 6,
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "defend"
      "value": 5,
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

There are usually many pairs of `trait_type` and `value` in `attributes` , a `attributes` in level 1 of `metadata` column. Pairs in `attributes` can be added arbitrarily. For example, I can add pair `{ "trait_type": "material", "value": "silk" }` into `attributes` in example above.

**Question:**

I want to perform a mix of multiple string matching searches and number in range searches. For example: `trait_type = material and 10 < defend < 20 and attract > 5`.

I have thought of separating `attributes` into a table with 2 colums `trait_type` and `value` and querying SQL using `intersect` but when adding more conditions, I have to add more `intersect` also and It is very ineffective.

Is there any table design, indexing strategy, tools... so I can effectively query that kind of data?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the free version of PostGreSQL will be unable to have some "in memory" features like Microsoft SQL Server, there is no proper way to ensure performances for those type of queries. The usual way to do that is to put the data in a key/value pair table in memory like Redis or some other specialized NoSQL DBMS do.